# earth movers distance RGB colors

Tags: image, numpy, scipy, distribution, similarity

I want to have a metric to match two `RGB` images with each other. I have been going through some mathematical formulas, to understand scipy's wasserstein distance `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance`. I understand the approach for greyscale images as followed:

1. convert both RGB images to greyscale
2. caluclate a histogram `np.histogram` with 255 bins, for each greyscale value one.
3. normalize the values
4. calculate the cumulative distribution (CDF) for each histogram
5. Calculate the area of both CDF's and calculate the dissimilarity ( wasserstein distance) between the two

This makes sense to me, I however do not understand on how to apply the same logic to an RGB image? My assumption is, that I would need to calculate the histograms for each color channel (RGB), then calculate the wasserstein distance between each color channel from the two images. 
Once I have the three distances, for each how do I proceed? How do I combine those distances?

Comment: Why don't you used something like `distance = (wasserstein_distanceRed + wasserstein_distanceGreen + wasserstein_distanceGreen) / 3`?
You can also use features detection (openCV lib does it) to compute distance between images.

Comment: I thought about it, to simply take the mean between the three channels. I think since their relationship is linear it makes sense